# What can cause situatuon where @EnableJpaRepositories doesn't detect @Repository beans while @ComponentScan does

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to start a SpringBoot application using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, however when using @EnableJpaRepositories on my main it does't find matching beans while annotating with @ComponentScan detects the @Repository beans. Can anyone hint what can be the case of that behaviour?

I've made sure that in my application.yml I have properties set to connect to local MySQL database instance and those are correct, my build.gradle.kts of module containing repositories is defining the api(spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) to be visible to other modules implementing it.

My main:

```
package com.missdermal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.missdermal")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.missdermal")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DermalManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DermalManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

one of repos:

```
package com.missdermal.repository;

import com.missdermal.entity.customer.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

[image: @EnableJpaRepositories]
[image: @ComponentScan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using IntelliJ but seems to me like an IntelliJ UI problem, it doesn't detect repository beans if you only have the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. However you should be able to inject the repositories and your application should work fine.

However I would advise you to use the specific packages for entities/repositories, it's a waste of resources to scan the whole project for entities/repositories that reside only in a specific package:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.missdermal.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.missdermal.entity")
```

Comment: I think you must be right about it, I'm capable of running app and doing intergration tests on @Repository beans as well without issues. Alos thanks for advice.